# Address and manipulate text in a textfield and footer in Word documents with R officer package

Tags: r, officer

I am working on a solution to change the text in several Word documents with similar structure. The text positions that I want to change are *1. in a textfield* related to the header/footer and *second in the first footer*. I don't know how to address the text inside these elements does anyone? Is it possible at all?
[Image of that document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLk6a.png)
Here is my example:

```
library(officer)
library(magrittr)

docact <- read_docx("PATH/officertest/textfieldfooter.docx")

docx_summary(docact)
```

doc_index content_type style_name                                                            text level num_id
1         1    paragraph         NA Here is some other text that is easy to address and manipulate.    NA     NA

```
cursor_reach(docact, keyword = "I want to address this textfield") %>%
  slip_in_text("This is the text that I want to add ", pos = "after", style = "Default Paragraph Font")
```

gives an Error: I want to address this textfield has not been found in the document

```
headers_replace_all_text(docact, "footertext", "the text that should be the replacement",
         only_at_cursor = FALSE,
         warn = TRUE)
```

Warning messages:
1: In header$replace_all_text(old_value, new_value, only_at_cursor,  :
  Found 0 instances of 'footertext' in the document.
2: In header$replace_all_text(old_value, new_value, only_at_cursor,  :
  Found 0 instances of 'footertext' in the document.
3: In header$replace_all_text(old_value, new_value, only_at_cursor,  :
  Found 0 instances of 'footertext' in the document.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this function in the officer package:

`docact <- footers_replace_all_text(docact,"old_value","new_value")`

Replacing text in a text field did not work for me yet